# springdoc-openapi-ui set servers using environment variables

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, maven-3, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have a static `openapi.yaml` file which looks something like this:

***Existing Yaml:***

```html
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: API
  description: >-
    Awesome API
  contact:
    name: bh4r4th
    email: nenethopu@gmail.com
  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    url: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
  version: 2.0.0
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:8080
    description: Dev Server
  - url: http://www.example.com
    description: Prod Server
```

Now,
I wanted to pass `servers` dynamically using an environment variable.

***Expected Yaml:***

```html
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: API
  description: >-
    Awesome API
  contact:
    name: bh4r4th
    email: nenethopu@gmail.com
  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    url: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
  version: 2.0.0
servers: ${SWAGGER_API_URLS}
```

**Why I wanted to do this?**

1. I am building my application as docker image and using same image for 100 different clients.
2. So, each client has their own set of `Dev` & `Prod` servers.

**I tried:**

1. Setting `@OpenAPIDefinition` on application
2. Adding Beans like `OpenApiCustomizer`, `OpenApi`, `GlobalOpenApiCustomizer`
   None worked.

Before I go hacky and edit actual file on docker build. I am looking for any simple solution out of the box saves tonnes of extra configuration.

Dependencies used:

```html
* springdoc-openapi-ui: 1.6.11

    * swagger-ui: 4.14.0
    
* spring-boot: 2.6.6

* maven: 3.8.1
```

Comment: You cannot use the classes mentioned to enrich a static file, the classes are used runtime, when generating the openapi with a @RestController or similar as base.

Comment: Yes Jan Nielsen, I couldn't supply urls with above mentioned classes. I solved this with a simple fix, which served my purpose. i.e., by removing `servers` from swagger completely. Which pointed to `/`by default. So, it points to application root path in my case. Suppose, if my application is running on http:/localhost:8000 then server points to http:localhost:8000/